# web form using master page doesn't take up the whole page

Tags: html, css, master-pages

Hello I've got a master page with this css file

```
html, body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#form1 {
     position:relative;
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
 }

 .header { 
  position:relative;
  height:10%;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #b9df66; 
 color: #FFF; 
 font-size: 10pt; 
 font-weight: bold; 
 padding-right: 5px; 
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
 } 


 .quote { 

  position:relative;
  height:2%;
 width: 100%; 
 background-color: #EEE; 
 color: #000; 
 font-size: 8pt; 
 font-weight: bold; 
 padding: 2px; 
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
 text-align: right; 
 } 

 .content
 {

   position:relative;
   float:right;
   height:80%;
   width:80%;
 border:3px solid blue;
 }

 .contentleft {
     position:relative;
     height:80%;
     width:16%;
     float:left;
     background :RGB(238,238,238);
     border: 1px solid red;

 }
```

Here is the html of MasterPage

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
        <link href="Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="header" >Bohemia
        </div>
    <div class="quote" >Because We are awesome </div>

    <div class="content" id="content" runat="server" >
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderMainMenu" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
        <div class="contentleft">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderLeftMenu" runat="server"/>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblproba" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

And the html of the page using ygismaster page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Search_FormMP.aspx.cs"
     Inherits="Tanya_Marinova_FN_0801262079_reservation_system.Search_FormMP" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderMainMenu" runat="server">
     <asp:GridView ID="GridViewCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            AllowPaging="True" datakeynames="Reservation_ID,Excursion_ID"
            onpageindexchanging="GridViewCustomers_PageIndexChanging"
            onrowcommand="GridViewCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            onrowdatabound="GridViewCustomers_RowDataBound" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Horizontal" >


            <Columns>

              </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelSelectedItem" runat="server"></asp:Label>



</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderLeftMenu" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

No matter what I do it doesn't take up the whole page! What may be the problem

Answer (score 0):

In your page it seems that `<html>` element is missing

Remember to also add a strict doctype into your template, e.g. `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: could you reproduce the issue on a fiddle?

Comment: I  think the problem is that I'm using asp.net master page. It seems that it can't understand body,html{height:100%;}